# send sms to user group based on group it belongs to

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

First of all I will explain in brief regarding my requirement. I want
my users to be distributed in couple of groups say ABC, XYZ,
PQR....The users and groups will be managed through a website.....Now
i want that a user can send group sms just by sending a single sms to
any number say 999.

So If a user of group ABC send an sms to 999 then depending on which
group he belongs, the messages should be sent automatically to all
other users of that group.

I have no clue where to ask, whom to ask and what will i require so finally decided to  post a question here...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get an SMS Gateway account that will provide a way to send MT (outgoing) messages and receive MO (incoming) messages over an HTTP interface.

Search this site for; recommend sms gateway.

The MO part can be expensive, so an alternative in ~low volume scenarios is to use a GSM modem hosting a SIM card to do the receiving part (You can also of course use this to send).

Matching users to groups is unrelated to this mechanic and would be managed by a simple database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Now for a novice like me what you said is kind of difficult to understand but now I know that this is possible. So I will conclude that I have to find those who offer smsgateway right ???

And the alternative you specified in low volume is u meant by low volume of SMS right ? Between where can i get more information about How, Who can and Where the GSM modem can be used to host the sim ....?

Answer (score 0):

This is frequently referred to as 'group messaging' and can be very easily built using an SMS gateway like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) (where I work). [GroupMe](http://www.groupme.com), [Betwext](http://betwext.com/talk) and [Beluga](http://www.belugapods.com/) are popular group messaging products.

I have an example group messaging app written in ASP.NET MVC here: http://www.twilio.com/blog/2010/04/howto-build-a-group-sms-application-with-aspnet-mvc.html  You can write this in any web programming language however.

Comment: Thanks john.. So messaging to group from mobile is possible but I would like you notice that I dont have internet access on phone or i want to use an application for that. I want to send sms to group using simple sms service of provider. Of above products Betwext seems like doing what I need but I would like to have indepth information about the whole process and want to know what are the pre-requisite to achieve group messaging.....

Comment: The ones I list all support SMS, with GroupMe and Beluga offering a smart phone version as well.